# ServiceStack Free-quota

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm a bit confused about ServiceStack's free-quota statement on https://www.servicestack.net/download#free-quotas

If I read it correctly you're allowed unrestricted use of service stack services, as long as you use ServiceStack's own clients, right?

I made a litte test service project with 15 DTOs hosted in it, but when I F5 it  in Visual Studio the Apphost.Init() throws the dreaded licensing exception (The free-quota limit on '10 ServiceStack Operations' has been reached)

Am I misunderstanding the licensing statements, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I idn't read the whole thing, but it sounds like you need a license key to get the free stuff as well: quota's below which can be unlocked **with a license key** If you're talking about DTOs, it says 10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free-quota limit on '10 ServiceStack Operations' indicates you've exceeded 10 server operations in your AppHost. ServiceStack's Client Libraries allows unrestricted access to **consume ServiceStack Services** so clients can freely call your Services without a license, but to enable unrestricted usage in **creating ServiceStack Services** on the server beyond the free-quotas you'll need to register a commercial license key.

Comment: OK thanks, although I still  wouldn't call the licensing explanation on their site very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a license key to use Service Stack provided you stay under the listed quotas.

The quotas are (as of 9/6/2016)

- 10 Operations in ServiceStack (i.e. Request DTOs)
- 10 Database Tables in OrmLite
- 10 DynamoDB Tables in PocoDynamo
- 20 Different Types in Redis Client Typed APIs
- 6000 requests per hour with the Redis Client

Based on your stated usage, you have 15 DTO's.  This exceeds the free usage limit of 10 DTO's, thus your exception.

If you are able to drop it down to 10, you will no longer get the exception.

Comment: I have a simple service with an interface of 9 operations and I get the licensing exception. I had surpassed it earlier today, but when I removed some extra ones, I made sure it is under 10, but I still get the error. Does this flag stay on after you surpass it once?